# Error 500 after Laravel 5.4 upload

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a `laravel 5.4` app and I did upload this on a shared hosting server and did change `.env` file...

But I still have `error 500`

When I use `php error reporting`, this report will come from server:

> Warning: require(/home/axaanir/domains/photobooks.ir/public_html/vendor/composer/../guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions_include.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/axaanir/domains/photobooks.ir/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/axaanir/domains/photobooks.ir/public_html/vendor/composer/../guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions_include.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php-5.6/lib/php') in /home/axaanir/domains/photobooks.ir/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66

But these folder exists on the returned path by server...!!!
Does anyone know how should I fix this?

***Thanks in advance...***

Comment: Did you checked database connection?

Comment: @Mr.Developer Yes, I did...

Comment: have you linked the storage or have appropriate permissions ?

Comment: @NaveenNiraula yes, I made this even 777...!!!

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you run a composer install on the server.
2. check you can storage write permission to storage folder
3. You need to define path to public in your apache configuration to be
   able to open without public